# p:dataexporter columns with images

Tags: pdf, primefaces, jsf-2, export

I want to export a datatable (with `p:graphicImages` in columns) in PrimeFaces but even in the new version of PrimeFaces I can only see the alt: value of image in my PDF file. Can't I export graphicImage itself?

It's also asked in [this link](https://code.google.com/archive/p/primefaces/issues/4013) comment #3.

Answer (score 0):

No you can't, not without extending the exporter

Comment: Think so too but i'm kinda lost here I checked source code of the PDFExporter class of primefaces [link](https://github.com/primefaces-extensions/core/blob/master/src/main/java/org/primefaces/extensions/component/exporter/PDFExporter.java)  but couldnt find where to change exportValue functions always returns String is there a way to return different type

Answer (score 0):

I can give you two ideas of how I got to put in a pdf images:
1. Use a printer (), then print it to pdf and you're done. You will have your table with the pretty images.
2. Generate the PDF using iText and you can personalize it as far as you want.